# Bad predictions but good model accuracy using GCN

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning

I am using Graph Convolutional Network for Information Extraction from an Image with OCR Results. my Training set has a 45-50 set of data. At training the model I am able to get 85-90 percentage Accuracy with loss of 0.63094 But with that model when I try to predict it gives bad results. Please Help me to solve this problem.
Model Input Graph-based Adjacency Matrix - A, Features set - X, Labels- y
learning rate - 0.01
number hidden layer 2

Answer (score 0):

This may be because of a few things.

1. **don't have enough data**
2. **your features aren't sufficient for reliable predictions**
3. **you are overfitting**

But beyond what you've given I'm not sure. If you can provide some more information I may be able to help further.